# Can I use tethering to let an iPad use an iPhone's 3G?

Tags: iphone, ipad, tethering

Given an iPad that doesn't have 3G but only wifi, can I make this use the 3G connection of an iPhone 4?

Does this require a cable between the devices, or does it work over (bluetooth|wifi?) ?

Comment: With iOS 5 you can.  Both via Bluetooth or using the iPhone as a Wifi-hotspot.

Comment: Yes.. with iOS5 you now can (and depending on the carrier, pay extra). But this question was asked 2 years ago before iOS 5 was out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this with the stock phone, however if you decide to jailbreakyour iPhone, you could use an application like [MyWi](http://www.intelliborn.com/mywi.html) to share your iPhone's 3G connection over WiFi

Comment: I've left my iPhone at iOS 4.0.1 entirely to keep it jailbroken so I can use MyWi with my wifi iPad. No other reason.

Comment: Sounds like a great solution, but *wow* they're not ashamed of the price. Still worth considering, since 3G for iPad is more than $20, and less versatile. Thanks!

Comment: The only inconvenience of the MyWi 20$ solution is that you have to jailbreak your device to install it, thus limiting your natural ability to upgrade them until the “jailbreakers” come up with an updated solution, and you have the risk that a wrong update may break the jailbreak (sometimes forever).

Answer (score 3):

Official word here:

http://www.engadget.com/2010/03/05/hey-steve-can-the-ipad-tether-with-the-iphone/

Comment: +1 for the official word, but note that there are inofficial ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do this without Jailbraking your device (as correctly pointed by [Rex](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/95/rex)).

The iOS 4.x doesn’t (not even the latest developer 4.2) have a mechanism to tether with another iPhone/Pad. They can *share* their connection (via Bluetooth for example) but I haven’t seen a way to tell an iPhone -> pair with that other iPhone and use that internet connection. That is something a Macintosh computer can do, but I don’t believe you can do that with your iPad/Phone.

Comment: Is there a word missing in your sentence "*The iOS 4.x (not even...*"? It sounds halfway self-contradictory to me.

Comment: @torbengb indeed, thanks (note to self: don’t reply late at night). ;)

Comment: You fixed it, now it makes sense to me, too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I regularly tether my iPad 2 to my iPhone 4 via bluetooth. However you'll need an unlocked iPhone.